# MsiDatabaseOpenView returning 1615 (ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX) with seemingly valid query

Tags: windows-installer

I'm trying to use `MsiDatabaseOpenView` to manipulate an `.msi` installer and I am receiving an error that I cannot diagnose.

When invoking `MixDatabaseOpenView`, the method is returning the error code `1615`.  The [method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370082%28VS.85%29.aspx) indicates `ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX` as a possible error result, and `1615` maps to `ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX` according to [the installer error codes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229683).  Calling `MsiGetLastErrorRecord` for additional details and passing the resulting handle to `MsiFormatRecord` results in the following data (line breaks and indenting added at whitespace for readibility; generified service name and msi installer/database path):

```
1: 2237 
2: C:\path\to\myinstaller.msi
3: INSERT INTO `ServiceInstall` 
   (`ServiceInstall`,`Name`, `DisplayName`, `ServiceType`, `StartType`, 
    `ErrorControl`, `LoadOrderGroup`, `Dependencies`, `StartName`,
    `Password`, `Arguments`, `Component_`, `Description` ) 
   VALUES 
   ('ServiceInstall.ServiceName','ServiceName' ,'My Service' , 16 , 2 , 
    1 ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'C__E2E295F8B94A1C97F5DA47AACC498002' ,
    'My Service Description' ) 
4:
```

The first value  -- `2237` -- is a [windows installer error message number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28VS.85%29.aspx) that corresponds to "Invalid or missing query string" (which is consistent with the `ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX` result code).  The query string, however, seems fine to me.  It's certainly not missing as the data is provided back from `MsiGetLastErrorRecord`, and as far as I can see (though I may be missing something), it conforms to the [proper format for the insert query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021%28VS.85%29.aspx), and the columns [match the valid columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371637%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Any ideas on what may be causing this operation to fail and how it may be resolved?

Also, though I don't think it should matter, here are the declarations I am using to gain access to the Msi API methods:

```
[DllImport("msi")]
private static extern int MsiDatabaseOpenView(IntPtr handle, string query, ref IntPtr viewhandle);
[DllImport("msi")]
private static extern IntPtr MsiGetLastErrorRecord();
[DllImport("msi")]
private static extern int MsiFormatRecord(IntPtr empty, IntPtr errhandle, StringBuilder extradata, ref int len);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of experimentation, removing the data insertion for the `Description` field allows things to work properly, although I'm not sure why this would be the case.  The behavior was not fixed or otherwise changed when using an empty (`""`) or null ("`[~]`") value for `Description`, nor did changing the order of where Description was in the field list made any difference; removing was the only way that I could get it to work.