# MsiDatabaseOpenView returns 1615 with 2 transforms

Tags: windows-installer

I found [MsiDatabaseOpenView returning 1615 (ERROR_BAD_QUERY_SYNTAX) with seemingly valid query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499930/msidatabaseopenview-returning-1615-error-bad-query-syntax-with-seemingly-valid) but that doesn't seem to be quite the same issue - in that one, the query was modified and worked without a particular insertion.  I also found a post somewhere that discussed the same error but the cause there was that the table being queried didn't exist.

In my case, the query should be truly simple:  SELECT * FROM `Property` (Doesn't have to be the Property table, any table gives the same result).  The code used to do the query is also simple:

```
IntPtr dbhandle = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr viewhandle = IntPtr.Zero;
int result = 0;

MsiOpenDatabase(@"<base MSI path goes here>", (IntPtr)2, ref dbhandle);

// Apply transforms 1 and 2
MsiDatabaseApplyTransform(dbhandle, @"<first transform path>", 0);
MsiDatabaseApplyTransform(dbhandle, @"<second transform path>", 0);

viewhandle = IntPtr.Zero;
result = MsiDatabaseOpenView(dbhandle, "SELECT * FROM `Property`", ref viewhandle);
```

The wierd part:  I only get the return of 1615 when there are two transforms.  Either transform individually works and the package installs correctly with both transforms in place.  We've got several apps that have two transforms and they all have the same behavior.

Both of the MsiDatabaseApplyTransform calls seem to be working (at least they return 0).  Turning on MSI logging does not create any logs.

Anyone have any idea what's happening/where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at what [MsiGetLastErrorRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells you. Also consider setting the [`Debug` policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/21/471793.aspx) to get some deeper information shunted to a log (I believe it shows up in the debug stream viewable with [dbgview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)).

Comment: Thank you, but I think I am more confused than I was.  

The debug policy and MsiGetLastErrorRecord are both in agreement:  1: 2229 2: <path> 3: Property 4: SELECT * FROM `Property`.  

All I can tell about 2229 though is that it's for when the table doesn't exist (or it couldn't load it) but I'd really expect that the Property table was indeed there.

Comment: Ok - this is just silly.  With just the code above - not with the MsiGetLastErrorRecord - with no transforms or one transform, it works.  With two transforms, not only does it give the 1615 but it also corrupts the base MSI (as in a binary diff shows actual changes between the two).

Comment: Have you tried `MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT` or `MSIDBOPEN_READONLY` instead of `MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT`? (appears to be 1 or 0 instead of 2)